# Nested Loop including Average of Integers

Tags: c++, loops, nested, average

Good day,

I have a C++ assignment that states:

"create a program that asks the user for an infinite amount of numbers until the user enters zero. Out of the numbers entered, find the largest and smallest number and also the amount of numbers that were entered and the average of those numbers.

*The output should look like the following:*

the largest number entered is:

the smallest number entered is:

the average of the: ____ numbers is: ____

**I am able to output the max and min numbers, but I cannot figure out how to also incorporate the amount of inputs and also calculate the average.**

**The program below outputs the max and min numbers entered, but I do not even know where to start for the average and amount of numbers input. I have spent many hours on this and yes, I have read my book over and over. There is no specific application for all of these requests in one program Help??**

```
#include <iostream>              

#define PI 3.14159
using namespace std;

main() - the function that executes


int main()                                      

int number = 1;
int maxNumber = 0;
int minNumber = 0;
int counter = 0;

while (number != 0)
{
      std::cout << "enter an integer: " << endl;
      cin >> number;

    if (counter == 0)
{
      maxNumber = number;
      minNumber = number;
}
   else
{
   if (number > maxNumber && number != 0)
      maxNumber = number;

   else if (number < minNumber && number != 0)
           minNumber = number;
}
         counter++;
}

std::cout << "\nthe largest number entered is " << maxNumber << endl;
std::cout << "\nthe largest number entered is " << minNumber << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, your `else if` is missing a final `else` clause.

Comment: dont you think the counter gives the number of inputs?? average would be sum/counter if you get the sum.

Comment: You should check `number` for 0, before the first `if` statement.

Comment: You're right, the counter does give the number of inputs. Sorry! My mind is out of it from staring at the screen so long. Any suggestions for the calculations for the sum?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Answer should give you an idea. Hint: search for "+=",

Comment: Which one of Thomas Matthews are you referring to? I am at a complete loss on this. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to calculate the sum, since there are an infinite amount of numbers that could be entered before entering zero

Answer (score 2):

You need a `sum` variable.  Add `number` to the `sum` variable.

After inputting all the numbers, divide `sum` by `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a for loop to track the total sum and the counter:

for ( sum=0, counter=0, number=1; number!=0 ; sum+=number, ++counter)
    cin>>number;

```
etc..
```

Comment: if the goal is to write the most compact code, that might be a winner. but i'd rather recommend anyone focus on writing readable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thank you everyone! It took me way too long, but thanks to everyone's comments, I finally pieced together what I needed in order to run a successful program.

It was: sum += number for the sum calculation. Stupid tired eyes miss the obvious all too often.

Thank you all very much!